# Background image in IE8 (Windows 7) is not showing up ...?

Tags: css

In Windows XP IE8 renders the background image ok > [www.stichtingkarkas.com](http://www.stichtingkarkas.com) ... why not in Windows 7 ... !?

CSS:

```
/* background > http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background.asp */
header {
    max-width: none;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    height: 500px;
    background: #fff url(../design/3396502015_cf3321bb7b_o_daddy.jpg) no-repeat 50% 30%;
}
```

Comment: Seems to be working now, how did you fix it ? :-)

Comment: Typo in HTML (`<h1">`) and wrong order .js files ... :%

Answer (score 0):

The main issue was the wrong order of .js files ... now main .js files are at the top of HTML (again) ... first jQuery and thereafter the HTML5 conditional `lt IE 9` ... :)

I would be very grateful if somebody could say something about how to put as much .js files at the bottom of a (this) HTML page.

Comment: A lot of ground to recover > https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/ ... :)